# Does diffraction of a coherent laser beam affect its polarization state?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, laser, polarization, diffraction

Suppose I have a collimated laser beam with an arbitrary polarization state - linear, circular, or elliptical. The beam encounters an obstacle, such as a pinhole. Diffraction occurs as photons scattered off the boundaries of the pinhole interfere with photons spanning the radial profile of the beam.

Now, at any point during this process, does the polarization state of my beam change as a result of the diffraction?

Comment: Diffraction does not occur through the process you indicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, diffraction can lead to polarization effects. However, this requires moving out of the regime of scalar optics. Scalar optics is the regime when you can neglect the polarization of light and only treat its spatial complex amplitude.

Scalar optics can break down when the paraxial limit breaks down. This happens around when you introduce spatial features into your field which are close to as small as or smaller than the wavelength of light you are considering.

A good example of this is an extremely tightly focused Gaussian beam.
Suppose the beam is propagating along the $z$ direction.
To use some language from Fourier optics. If the focus is so small it means the beam is composed of a very large range of wavevectors $k_x$ and $k_y$. The plane waves corresponding to these large wavevectors can have a large angle with the optical axis. That means it is possible for those plane waves with large transverse wavevectors to have large components in the direction of propagation. This is not what is typically the case for paraxial Gaussian beams which are purely transversely polarized.
At the focus the superposition of these polarization vectors can lead to surprising polarization patterns. See for example:

[Polarization of tightly focused laser beams](https://arxiv.org/ftp/physics/papers/0305/0305065.pdf)

You ask specifically about diffraction. Well just reverse the effect I have described above. Shine a transversely linearly polarized plane wave onto an opaque screen which has a hole on it with dimensions on the order of $\lambda$. What you will find is that in the vicinity of the hole the diffracted light will have non-transverse polarization.

Answer (score 0):

Polarization of light is not dependent on diffraction.

Reflection of light from a surface can lead to polarization changes.  Frankly just travelling through a birefringent media (a material where the refractive index is different in each direction) can change polarization states.